# Unknown error for basic registration

Tags: php, html, registry, parse-error

i have this error

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in receive/register.php on line 1`

My receive/register.php is

```
<?php
$_POST['username'] = $username;
$_POST['password1'] = $password;
$_POST['password2'] = $passwordagain;
$_POST['email'] = $email;

echo $username.'<br>'.$password.'<br>'.$passwordagain.'<br>'.$email;

if (!isset($username) || !isset($password) || !isset($passwordagain) || !isset($email))
{   /*
$_SESSION['regerrorid'] = '0';
$_SESSION['regerrormsg'] = 'Not all fields are completed';
header ('Location: ./'.$directory.'register');*/
echo'uhm';
}
?>
```

And the one that sends the info is

```
<?php
/* !!!!only if the code works
$_SESSION['regerrorid'] = $success;
$_SESSION['regerrormsg'] = $message;
*/
?>
<div class='registration-<?php echo $success; ?>'><?php echo $message; ?></div><br>
<form action="receive/register.php" method="POST">
  <span style='font-size:14px;font-family:"Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace'>Username:</span><input class='lolquired' type="text" name="username" /><br />
  <span style='font-size:14px;font-family:"Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace'>Password:</span><input class='lolquired' type="password" name="password1" /><br />
  <span style='margin-left:-56px;font-size:14px;font-family:"Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace'>Repeat Password:</span><input class='lolquired' type="password" name="password2" /><br />
  <span style='margin-left:24px;font-size:14px;font-family:"Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace'>Email:</span><input class='lolquired' type="email" name="email" /><br /><br />
  <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form><?php 
/* !!!!only if the code works
$_SESSION['regerrorid'] = '';
$_SESSION['regerrormsg'] = '';
*/
```

Comment: No funky characters in the file or anything, right?  Perhaps I'm missing it, but I don't see how this error can happen.

Comment: nope no funky characters. I have some /* */ that im not showing because it was like that and its a comment just for myself.

Comment: You should provide more detail, there is no syntax error in the PHP code you posted. – I just ran it in the PHP interactive shell and it worked fine.

Comment: Can you paste the entire file?

Comment: No, paste it with comments and everything.

Comment: That code does not have a syntax error. If you don't throw out your assumptions about what you know we can't help you further.

Comment: someone upvoted this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shouldn't it be:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

etc....

When I used your code I got $username is undefined error on php 5.3.5

also noticed... if you're using $_SESSION you need to add

```
session_start();
```

at the top of your code